# Splitting a string at compile time gives different results on different compilers

Tags: c++, gcc, visual-c++, clang, c++17

I'm trying to split a string at compile time. I defined a function `split` like

```
#include <array>
#include <string_view>

template <std::size_t N>
constexpr std::array<std::string_view, N> split(std::string_view str)
{
    std::array<std::string_view, N> arr{};
    std::size_t start = 0, end = 0;

    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < N && end != std::string_view::npos; i++)
    {
        end = str.find_first_of(',', start);    
        arr[i] = str.substr(start, end - start);
        start = end + 1;
    }

    return arr;
}
```

Given the usage like:

```
constexpr std::string_view str = "one,two,three,four,five";
constexpr std::array<std::string_view, 5> arr = split<5>(str);
```

msvc and gcc both compile. However clang already rejects this code saying `std::string_view::find_first_of` doesn't result in a constant expression (is this a compiler bug?).

When I test the result like:

```
int main() 
{
    std::cout << str << "\n\n";

    for (auto i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++)
        std::cout << arr[i] << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

msvc prints

```
one,two,three,four,five

one
two
thr
e,f
ur,
```

while gcc gives me the expected result

```
one,two,three,four,five                                                                                                                                                           

one
two
three
four
five
```

I added a second split function that is identical to the original one, except it prints out the intermediate substring inside the split function. Both msvc and gcc print the same in that case which is the expected result above.

Why are the results different? Did I invoke UB somewhere?

The complete code can be found [here](https://godbolt.org/z/q8PSkz)

### Edit

It looks like this is a bug in msvc. Invoking the function at runtime produces the expected result:

```
int main() 
{
    std::cout << str << "\n\n";

    for (auto i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++)
        std::cout << arr[i] << "\n";

    auto arr2 = split<5>(str);    
    for (auto i = 0; i < arr2.size(); i++)
        std::cout << arr2[i] << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

### Edit 2

Looks like there is actually a bug inside msvc when it runs the interpreter for the constant expressions. I've added another function to access the variables outside the function:

```
constexpr decltype(split<5>(str)) arr = split<5>(str);
constexpr decltype(split_sizes<5>(str)) arr_sizes = split_sizes<5>(str);

template <std::size_t N>
constexpr std::array<std::array<std::size_t, 3>, N> split_sizes(std::string_view str)
{
    std::array<std::array<std::size_t, 3>, N> arr{};
    std::size_t start = 0, end = 0;

    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < N && end != std::string_view::npos; i++)
    {
        end = str.find_first_of(',', start);
        auto sub = str.substr(start, end - start);
        arr[i] = { sub.length(), start, end };
        start = end + 1;
    }

    return arr;
}

int main() 
{    
    for (auto i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++)
        std::cout << arr[i] << "\tlen=" << arr_sizes[i][0] << " start=" << arr_sizes[i][1] << " end=" << arr_sizes[i][2] << "\n";

    std::cout << "\n";
    auto arr2 = split<5>(str);
    auto arr_sizes2 = split_sizes<5>(str);

    for (auto i = 0; i < arr2.size(); i++)
        std::cout << arr2[i] << "\tlen=" << arr_sizes2[i][0] << " start=" << arr_sizes2[i][1] << " end=" << arr_sizes2[i][2] << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

gives the following result on msvc:

```
one,two,three,four,five

one     len=3 start=0 end=3
two     len=3 start=4 end=7
thr     len=3 start=8 end=11
e,f     len=3 start=12 end=15
ur,     len=3 start=16 end=19

one     len=3 start=0 end=3
two     len=3 start=4 end=7
three   len=5 start=8 end=13
four    len=4 start=14 end=18
five    len=4 start=19 end=18446744073709551615
```

[Here](https://godbolt.org/z/ApjeS1) is a link to the updated, complete code.

Comment: Note: clang will compile it if you add `-stdlib=libc++` flag

Comment: I don't know about compiler error, maybe the problem is that there is no for constexpr in the c++17 standard?

Answer (score 1):

It's actually a compiler bug. I don't know what exactly is responsible for the bug, but it is inside `std::string_view::find_first_of`. Strangely enough, this bug only occurs during constant evaluation (at compile time). The runtime behaviour of this function is as expected as far as I can tell.

Here is the working implementation of `split`:

```
template <std::size_t N>
constexpr std::array<std::string_view, N> split(std::string_view str)
{
    std::array<std::string_view, N> arr{};
    std::size_t start = 0, end = 0;

    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < N && end != std::string_view::npos; i++)
    {
        end = std::string_view::npos;
        for (std::size_t j = start; j < str.length(); j++)
        {
            if (str[j] == ',')
            {
                end = j;
                break;
            }
        }

        arr[i] = str.substr(start, end - start);        
        start = end + 1;
    }

    return arr;
}
```

### Edit

Turns out msvc is very bad at evaluating constant expressions compared to gcc and clang. I found lots of other scenarios (all around `std::string_view`) that also fail to compile.

Comment: "It's actually a compiler bug" - of which compiler?

Comment: Msvc. The original code works fine with gcc (didn't run it with clang, but it compiles).